# Nginx not listening to ports

Tags: node.js, curl, nginx

I am trying to set up a Nginx as a reverse proxy to access multiple NodeJS apps running on the same server.

I have my nodeJS apps running with PM2 and it all seems fine:

[image]

My nodeJS app is the simple nodeJS app generated with express-generator, so it is supposed to be running on port 3000.

I have also set up my Nginx with the following config

```
server {
    listen 1004;

    server_name pumadashboard.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

However when I curl 127.0.0.1:1004 I get a badGateway error from Nginx. I am also not able to access pumadashboard.com from anywhere on my local network, it just loads until timeout.

Comment: The title is misleading. If you get error from nginx it definitely listens to the port. Check nginx's error.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you get if you do:

```
curl http://locahost:3000
```

This should give back a response and like that you will understand if the application started properly.

This nginx configuration works for me

```
upstream pumadashboard.com {
  server 127.0.0.1:3010;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name pumadashboard.com;
    root <path to your node application>;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/your-access.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/your-error.error.log;

    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_pass http://pumadashboard.com/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 240s;
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, all that happens is if i now access my webserver with the IP address in my brower wihtout specifying the port so just like 192.168.0.100 it goes to the app, however the url does not work.

Comment: The first step works. The fact that you can see your app with the ip, without specifying the port means that nginx forwards the traffic to your app. About the domain is another issue probably there is something miscofigure on your provider. Do you use aws route53?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 80;
```

to your `location /` block